# Read only defined columns of CSV

Tags: python, csv, data-structures

I wrote a python program that joins 2 csv tables according to a matching key.

My data looks like this:

Table 1:

```
 ID;NAME;ADRESS;TEL
 1; Lee; Str.; 12345
 2; Chu; Blv.; 34567
```

Table 2:

```
 AID; FID; XID
 50    1    99
 676   2    678
```

My code looks like this:

```
data = OrderedDict()
fieldnames = []

with open(join_file, "rt") as fp:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fp, dialect=excel_semicolon)
        fieldsB = reader.fieldnames
    fieldnames.extend(fieldsB)
    for row in reader:
        data.setdefault(row["FID"], {}).update(row)

with open(fileA, "rt") as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp, dialect=excel_semicolon)
    fieldnames.extend(reader.fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        data.setdefault(row["ID"], {}).update(row)

fieldnames = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(fieldnames))

with open("merged2.csv", "wt", newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, dialect=excel_semicolon)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for row in data.values():
        writer.writerow([row.get(field, '') for field in fieldnames],)
```

The join operation works like this, but my problem is that I want to remove certain fields from table 2 from the joined csv (e.g. XID). Is there a simple way to do this?

My solution prior to this was using `Pandas` but the script should run on a server where I don't want to (can't) install the dependencies for the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to take something out you can put in a simple filter using list comprehension.

You create the list here.

```
fieldnames = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(fieldnames))
```

filter out what you do not want.

```
filtered_fieldnames = [x for x in fieldnames if x != 'XID']
```

Then change the new file data to the filtered list.

```
with open("merged2.csv", "wt", newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(filtered_fieldnames)
    for row in data.values():
        writer.writerow([row.get(field, '') for field in filtered_fieldnames],)
```

You can wrap it in a function and call it when you either create a new file or wish to take something out..

```
def create_merged_file(names):

    with open("merged2.csv", "wt", newline='') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp)
        writer.writerow(names)
        for row in data.values():
            writer.writerow([row.get(field, '') for field in names],)

create_merged_file(fieldnames)

filtered_fieldnames = [x for x in fieldnames if x != 'XID']

create_merged_file(filtered_fieldnames)
```